# iOS SpriteKit - Possibly backward screen coordinates bug?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios8, sprite-kit

I know i must be doing something stupid. 
But to me, right now, it seems that the coordinates (X, Y) are reversed.

I have an app that is defined to be Portrait mode only.
I get the width and height by using the self.view.frame.size.
The dimensions is printed as: "width: 768, height: 1024".

However, when i draw simple things i discovered that i get the picture i expect IF I SWAP the coordinates.

Is this either a bug or am i missing something?

Snippet below draws a 4 lines (tic tac toe lines).
Note that this should draw the tic tac toe correctly, where the vertical lines are drawn using the **width** variable (*unexpected*).
The original (incorrect) code drew the vertical lines using the **height** variable (*expected*).

```
    int dimension = 3;
    int lineWidth = 10;
    int border = 20;

    int width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    int height = self.view.frame.size.height;
    int segment = self.view.frame.size.width / dimension;

    NSLog(@"width: %d, height: %d", width, height);

    // debug line.
    SKShapeNode *yourline = [SKShapeNode node];
    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, 0, 0);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, height, width);
    yourline.path = pathToDraw;
    [yourline setStrokeColor: [ UIColor greenColor]];
    [yourline setLineJoin: kCGLineJoinRound];
    [yourline setLineWidth: lineWidth];
    [self addChild: yourline];

    // vertical lines.
    for (int x = 1; x <= dimension; x++)
    {
        SKShapeNode *yourline = [SKShapeNode node];
        CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, x * segment, border);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, x * segment, width - border * 2);
        yourline.path = pathToDraw;
        [yourline setStrokeColor: [UIColor redColor]];
        [yourline setLineJoin: kCGLineJoinRound];
        [yourline setLineWidth: lineWidth];
        [self addChild: yourline];
    }

    // horizontal lines.
    for (int y = 1; y <= dimension; y++)
    {
        SKShapeNode *yourline = [SKShapeNode node];
        CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, border, y * segment);
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, height - border * 2, y * segment);
        yourline.path = pathToDraw;
        [yourline setStrokeColor: [ UIColor redColor]];
        [yourline setLineJoin: kCGLineJoinRound];
        [yourline setLineWidth: lineWidth];
        [self addChild: yourline];
    }
```

*** Update ***
To be clear, in order for me to draw something where i expect things to be drawn, i have to swap the x and y coordinate.

*** Resolved ***

The problem was that in my scene file (.sks) the dimensions was landscape mode. This totally dictates the width and height, which is what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

SpriteKit uses standard graph-style co-ordinates: (0, 0) in the bottom left, X going rightwards, Y going upwards, Z out of the screen towards you.

This differs from standard screen co-ordinates: (0, 0) in the top left.

Read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Nodes/Nodes.html

Answer (score 0):

you could say uikit does it 'wrong' starting at the TL corner,

spritekit / corgraphics / OpenGL / OS X by default all use a Cartesian coordinate system (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system)